# Is it possible to add TransformedTargetRegressor into a scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am setting up a predictive analytics pipeline on some data, and I am in the process of model selection. My target variable is skewed, so I would like to log-transform it in order to increase the performance of my linear regression estimators. I came across the relatively new `TransformedTargetRegressor` of scikit-learn, and I thought I could use it as part of a pipeline. I am attaching my code

My initial attempt was to transform `y_train` before calling `gs.fit()`, by casting it to `np.log1p(y_train)`. This works, and I can perform the nested cross-validation and return the metrics of interest for all estimators. However, I would like to be able to get R^2 and RMSE for the trained model on previously unseen data (validation set), and I understand that in order to do that, I need to use (for example) `r2_score` function on `y_val, preds`, where the predictions need to have been transformed back to the real values, i.e., `preds = np.expm1(gs.predict(X_val))`

```
### Create a pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([
    # the transformer stage is populated by the param_grid
    ('transformer', TransformedTargetRegressor(func=np.log1p, inverse_func=np.expm1)),
    ('reg', DummyEstimator())  # Placeholder Estimator
])

### Candidate learning algorithms and their hyperparameters
alphas = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
param_grid = [  
                {'transformer__regressor': Lasso(),
                 'reg': [Lasso()], # Actual Estimator
                 'reg__alpha': alphas},
                {'transformer__regressor': LassoLars(),
                 'reg': [LassoLars()], # Actual Estimator
                 'reg__alpha': alphas},
                {'transformer__regressor': Ridge(),
                 'reg': [Ridge()], # Actual Estimator
                 'reg__alpha': alphas},
                {'transformer__regressor': ElasticNet(),
                 'reg': [ElasticNet()], # Actual Estimator
                 'reg__alpha': alphas,
                 'reg__l1_ratio': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]}]


### Create grid search (Inner CV)
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1,
                  scoring=scoring, refit='r2', return_train_score=True)


### Fit
best_model = gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

### scoring metrics for outer CV
scoring = ['neg_mean_absolute_error', 'r2', 'explained_variance', 'neg_mean_squared_error']

### Outer CV
linear_cv_results = cross_validate(gs, X_train, y_train_transformed,
                                   scoring=scoring, cv=5, verbose=3, return_train_score=True)

### Calculate mean metrics
train_r2 = (linear_cv_results['train_r2']).mean()
test_r2 = (linear_cv_results['test_r2']).mean()
train_mae = (-linear_cv_results['train_neg_mean_absolute_error']).mean()
test_mae = (-linear_cv_results['test_neg_mean_absolute_error']).mean()
train_exp_var = (linear_cv_results['train_explained_variance']).mean()
test_exp_var = (linear_cv_results['test_explained_variance']).mean()
train_rmse = (np.sqrt(-linear_cv_results['train_neg_mean_squared_error'])).mean()
test_rmse = (np.sqrt(-linear_cv_results['test_neg_mean_squared_error'])).mean()
```

Obviously this code snippet does not work, because apparently I can not add `TransformedTargetRegressor` into my pipeline, since it does not have a `transform` method (I get this `TypeError`: *TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform*).

Is there a "proper" way of doing this, or do I just have to take the log transformation of `y_val` on the fly when I want to call `r2_score` function etc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, because the scikit-learn original `Pipeline` does not change the `y` or the number of samples in `X` and `y` during the steps.

Your use-case is little unclear. What is the need of `reg` step if that same `reg` is already added to the `TransformedTargetRegressor`?

Looking at the [documentation of `TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html), the parameter `regressor` accepts a regressor (which can be also a pipeline which have some feature selection operations on `X` and a regressor at final stage). The working of `TransformedTargetRegressor` will be:

```
fit():

    regressor.fit(X, func(y))

predict():

    inverse_func(regressor.predict(X))
```

So there is no need to append that same regressor as a new step. Your model selection code now can be:

```
pipe = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressos = DummyEstimator(),
                                  func=np.log1p, 
                                  inverse_func=np.expm1)),

### Candidate learning algorithms and their hyperparameters
alphas = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
param_grid = [  
                {'transformer__regressor': Lasso(),
                 'transformer__regressor__alpha': alphas},
                {'transformer__regressor': LassoLars(),
                 'transformer__regressor__alpha': alphas},
                {'transformer__regressor': Ridge(),
                 'transformer__regressor__alpha': alphas},
                {'transformer__regressor': ElasticNet(),
                 'transformer__regressor__alpha': alphas,
                 'transformer__regressor__l1_ratio': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]}
              ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it to wrap your pipeline:

```py
model = TransformedTargetRegressor(
    regressor=pipe,
    func=np.log1p, 
    inverse_func=np.expm1
)
.
.
.
gs = GridSearchCV(model, ...
```